# I'm using Jodit-react editor package, how can I insert some HTML on Cursor position in the editor

Tags: reactjs, html-editor, jodit

Previously I was using suneditor-react package, in which there was already a prop named insertHTML={} through which I could insert some HTML at the cursor position in the editor after listening an event, due to some limitations I've shifted to Jodit-react editor, but here there's not any such way I found where I can give a prop to insert some HTML, what should be the solution if I want to do so.